# Emailing committers of upstream jobs when downstream job fails

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Once a job builds the code successfully, it triggers test job as a downstream job.

My requirement is to send emails to committers in upstream job if the downstream test job failed.

I know I can do this:

```
{SCRIPT, script="committers.groovy"}
```

But the challenge is to write the Groovy script.

Comment: Why?
There is a perfectly good plugin for that.

Comment: @JoachimNilsson Hey Joachim , which plugin is that? Please let me know. We are using Git.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin